# how to use hlsConfig in react-hls-player

Tags: reactjs, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I came across https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hls-player where it is mentioned how to use hls player in reactjs
This is sample code i have written but i couldn't figureout how to use `hlsConfig` object. Can someone help me how and where to use hlsConfig object ?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHlsPlayer from 'react-hls-player'

export default class HLSPlayer extends React.Component {


render() {
    return (
        <ReactHlsPlayer
            url='https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8'
            autoplay={true}
            controls={true}
            width="1200"
            height="auto"
        />

    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The document is saying you can use all the options available here https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#fine-tuning. Here is an example:

```js
<ReactHlsPlayer
  url='https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8'
  autoplay={true}
  controls={true}
  width="1200"
  height="auto"
  hlsConfig={{
    autoStartLoad: true,
    startPosition: -1,
    debug: false,
    // ...
  }}
/>
```